# How to combine two or more mysql array in one

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two table that has multiple rows. I want to combine those two tables rows into one long array which will be identified as one array
I wrote this code

```
$posts_sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id < $lastpost AND position = submitter order by id DESC LIMIT 5");
$posts_all = $db->fetch_all($posts_sql);
foreach($posts_all as $key => $posts_row){
$users_sql = $db->query("SELECT username,firstname,lastname,avatar FROM users WHERE username = '".$posts_row['submitter']."'");
$users_all = $db->fetch_assoc($users_sql);
$data[] = $posts_row;
$data[] = $users_all;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

It makes duplicate arrays doesn't right...

That's how my result show

```
[{
"id":"39",
"hash":"070fcc8e73ba5f549f87",
"post":"hello\n",
"files":"",
"location":", 
"GB","status":"1",
"position":"dabblos",
"submitter":"dabblos",
"source":"text",
"ip":"37.130.227.133",
"stamp":"1390197699"
},
{
"username":"dabblos",
"firstname":"dabb",
"lastname":"los",
"avatar":"no_avatar.png"
}]
```

please help me make it just one long array

I would like to see the output looks like this

```
{
"id":"39",
"hash":"070fcc8e73ba5f549f87",
"post":"hello\n",
"files":"",
"location":", 
"GB","status":"1",
"position":"dabblos",
"submitter":"dabblos",
"source":"text",
"ip":"37.130.227.133",
"stamp":"1390197699"
"username":"dabblos",
"firstname":"dabb",
"lastname":"los",
"avatar":"no_avatar.png"
}
```

Comment: say i wanted to render avatar, it render it twice if used IMG tag html

Comment: can you show us, how you wanted the output look like?

Comment: It is a quirk of json_encode, if you look at the encode options in the manual: [function.json-encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) there is no way to force the write of an array, it writes objects instead. However, **[When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**
]

Comment: how about if we union all the two tables?

Comment: would work, make sure you order them correctly. The answers provide are going to be as good as it gets without editing the encode string. PHP  json_encode is rather 'quirky'

Comment: i'm pretty new to mysql, can you help me with rewrite the mysql code?

Comment: it is not worthwhile doing unless you have performance issues and it will make modifying it and changing it more work.

Comment: glad it all worked out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
$posts_sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id < $lastpost AND position = submitter order by id DESC LIMIT 5");
$posts_all = $db->fetch_all($posts_sql);
foreach($posts_all as $key => $posts_row) {
   $users_sql = $db->query("SELECT username,firstname,lastname,avatar FROM users WHERE username = '".$posts_row['submitter']."'");
   $users_all = $db->fetch_assoc($users_sql);
   $data[] = $posts_row;  
   foreach($users_all as $user) 
    $data[] = $user; 
   } 
}


echo json_encode($data); 

// when you use json_decode use the 'true' flag as in 
// $decodedJson =  json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: i'm only getting the first row of each table

Answer (score 2):

look at this,i have taken example values, it is working fine as you wanted

```
$arr=array(array("abc"=>"1","def"=>"2"),array("abcc"=>"11","deff"=>"22"));

echo json_encode($arr);
$final = array();
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $final = array_merge($final, $item);
}
print_r($final);
```

**output**

```
[{"abc":"1","def":"2"},{"abcc":"11","deff":"22"}]//json_array

Array ( [abc] => 1 [def] => 2 [abcc] => 11 [deff] => 22 )//final array
```

**UPDATE**

json_encode the final array and you'll get the desired result

```
echo json_encode($final);
```

output

```
{"abc":"1","def":"2","abcc":"11","deff":"22"}
```

Comment: that's how my current output looks like
[{"abc":"1","def":"2"},{"abcc":"11","deff":"22"}]

I want only this
{"abc":"1","def":"2","abcc":"11","deff":"22"}

Comment: you have to json encode the finall array,see my update in answer

Comment: May i suggest, that since you scanned each element of the array anyway, then using 'array_merge' is not as clear as $target[] = $source. In efficiency terms,  as PHP has a 'compiler' pass, i suspect the code generated is identical anyway. me being pedantic :-(

Answer (score 0):

Merge them before you `json_encode` them:

```
$data[] = $posts_row;
$data2[] = $users_all;

$result = array_merge($data,$data2);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: nope, that actually made it worse...
now it looping through data1 before it jumps to data2